# failed to retrieve password hash for reserver user [elastic] at least one primary shard for the index [.security-7] is unavailable?

Tags: elasticsearch, bitnami, elasticsearch-x-pack

I ve installed elastic 8.5.x with xpack on kubernates (bitnami). At the begining it works well.

Somehow it crashed after one month (nearly) then when i looked error it says

```
failed to retrieve password hash for reserver user [elastic] at least one primary shard for the index [.security-7] is unavailable?
```

I tried `reset password` and `setup password` but it doesnt response because the **masters** are not up. It gives above error.

I disabled xpack and restar cluster then it works as expected. ( i saw .security-7 index and its green like all others and cluster health)

but when i try `setup password interactive`  it gives xpack disable error and try `reset password -u elastic -i` it gives error.

Also when i re try xpack enable with beginning masters it gives same error.

What i dont understand ;

When i enable **xpack** why it needs to read `.security-7` index , because i just want to leverage master nodes only then i want to start others.

How can i handle this issue?

Comment: I have some issue, after looking for other logs I got high disk watermark. just clear some storage and it works